# Highcharts Redrawing images based off of chart width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I'm drawing to redraw images on my highcharts based off of a certain width. Ive made some progress but i still cant redraw these images within values that would stay on my chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/jimbob25/V446C/

I've attached a fiddle which shows my problem. Also the code below is part of my solution thus far.

```
//Line 18
redraw: function () { //Gets called when the chart resizes
                var offset = (750 - chart.chartWidth);
                initDrawing(chart, offset);
                console.log(offset);
            }

 //Line 96  Call the initDrawing function on initial load so that it draws the arrows
 var offset = (750 - chart.chartWidth);
  initDrawing(chart, offset);

//Line 99, I have to then call init drwaing and pass in the offset so i know how far to redraw. Also i have to remove each of the arrows after each redraw.
    function initDrawing(chart, offset) {

    var renderer = chart.renderer;
    $("#goal1").remove();
    $("#goal2").remove();
```

Comment: So where are the marker's supposed to be placed?  At X percent of the bar?  What not place the image with a custom series marker (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.marker.symbol)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of your code that instead of doing the calculations yourself and trying to place the images using `chart.renderer`, it adds them as a customer marker scatter plot.  This way highcharts does the positioning math for you and it's a lot easier to maintain:

```
series: [{
        name: null,
        data: [100, 100, 100, 100],
        color: "#E9E9E9"
    },{
        type: 'scatter',
        data: [[0,75], [1,50], [2,35], [3,65]],
        marker: {
            symbol: 'url(http://i.imgur.com/42P7k7o.png?1)'
        }            
}]
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/V446C/8/).

Comment: Hi Mark how can i make it so that the green arrows are not directly on the bar but instead slightly above or below it?